# Horizontal scroll left + 50px on click jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to use jQuery to make a left arrow and right arrow scroll left and right by +50px either way when clicked, but it seems to just reset the page to scroll left 0.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="parallax">
    <a href="#" id="test"></a>
</div>
```

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        $("#parallax").scrollLeft(5000);
    });
});
```

Any help or insights would be really appreciated.

Comment: what does your markup look like, or do you have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) you could share?

Comment: what sort of element is the `#test` element, is it an `<a>` element ?

Comment: yes it is an a element the basic structure is a div with a large width and the a button inside it style { #parallax width 17000px }<div id="parallax"><a href="#" id="test"></a></div>

Comment: I have a demo that I will post for you that I created for a project at work. I'll post it as an answer in a moment

Comment: If this issue is resolved, you should accept the clearest answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default action of the `<a>` element, as a `href="#"` will always scroll to the top :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').scrollLeft(5000);
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r577s/)

Comment: your right adeneo, the body was the overflowing element thank you that works great! one more question if you have time, how would you + 50px along rather than go to 50px please?

Comment: @gilesadamthomas - was just testing it out, and yes, the body seems to be the element with the scrollbar.

Comment: how would you + 50px along rather than go to 50px please?

Answer (score 1):

As promised, here is the demo that I wrote. It was a rough draft and could use some cleaning. I also removed some of the company-related stuff, and there may be one or two styles that reference them, but other than that it should do what you want.

NOTE: this demo was designed for Chrome (styles include CSS3 effects with only the chrome properties - I wrote this fast and did not write it for compatibility - feel free to change and remove/add any necessary styles to make it compatible in other browsers)

Text Slider Demo
    
        body {
            background-color: rgb(252,252,252);
        }

```
    .demo {
        font-size: 16px;
        border: 2px solid rgb(200,200,200);
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin: 0px 0px 20px 30px;
    }

    .demo-inner-wrapper {
        width: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .demo-outer-wrapper {
        border: 2px solid rgb(200,200,200);
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 4px;
        width: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 4px;
    }

    .demo-entry-title {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .arrow {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 4px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid rgb(55,190,235);
        background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
        padding: 4px;
        width: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        color: rgb(30,180,230);
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .demo-hover {
        background-color: rgb(0,35,100);
        color: rgb(252,252,252);
    }

    .content {
        padding: 8px;
        width: 640px;
        border: 2px solid rgb(200,200,200);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .demo-information {
        font: 16px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .header {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: rgb(0,35,100);
    }

    .section-header {
        color: rgb(25,100,190);
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 4px;
    }

    .demo-information p {
        margin-left: 4px;
    }

    .demo-header {
        font: 18px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: rgb(0,35,100);
    }  

    .demo-content {
        margin-left: 8px;
        margin-top: 8px;   
    }      
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $left = $(".left-arrow");
        var $right = $(".right-arrow");
        var $et = $(".demo-entry-title");
        var $demoWrap = $(".demo-inner-wrapper");

        $left.mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).addClass("demo-hover");
            var width = $et.width();
            var marginStr = $et.css("margin-left");
            var margin = parseInt(marginStr.substring(0, marginStr.length - 2));
            console.log(margin, marginStr);
            var scrollTo = $demoWrap.width() - width;
            if (scrollTo < 0) {
                $et.animate({ "margin-left": scrollTo }, (margin - scrollTo) * 10);
                console.log(width, margin, scrollTo, (margin - scrollTo) * 10);
            }
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            $et.stop();
            $(this).removeClass("demo-hover");
        });

        $right.mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).addClass("demo-hover");
            var width = $et.width();
            var marginStr = $et.css("margin-left");
            var margin = parseInt(marginStr.substring(0, marginStr.length - 2));
            console.log(margin, marginStr);
            var scrollTo = $demoWrap.width() - width;
            if (scrollTo < 0) {
                $et.animate({ "margin-left": 0 }, -margin * 10);
                console.log(width, margin, scrollTo, -margin * 10);
            }
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            $et.stop();
            $(this).removeClass("demo-hover");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="demo-information">
            <div class="header">
                Text Slide Demo</div>
            <br />
            <div class="section-header">
                Overview</div>
            <p>
                The demo below is intended to illustrate the use of jQuery and CSS to create a slide
                effect text that is too long for its specified width, rather than wrapping the text
                onto multiple lines. The scripting involved is very light weight, and can easily
                be wrapped up into a jQuery plugin.
            </p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="demo">
            <div class="demo-header">
                Demo:</div>
            <div class="demo-content">
                <div class="demo-outer-wrapper">
                    <div class="demo-inner-wrapper">
                        <span class="demo-entry-title">This is an entry title that is too long for the section,
                            and here is me giving it even more length.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="demo-buttons">
                    <span class="arrow left-arrow">Left</span><span class="arrow right-arrow">Right</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry about the formatting issue. I just fixed it :)

Comment: your welcome :) I don't know why someone voted it down though... could you please vote it back up for me?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below link. I hope it'll help to clear the issue.

```
$('.left').click(function(){

  $('#container').scrollLeft(0);
}); 
var bb=0;
$('.right').click(function(){
bb++;
    $('#container').scrollLeft(bb*50);

});
```

**Solution :**
  [Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/balasamik/79fub1f3/34/)